# ViewController - how to use it properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

newbie question

1) do you create a ViewController per set of function or 
2) just 2 viewcontroller (one for when user is not logged in, and another when user is logged in)

which is the best way to do it? any example how to use viewcontroller properly?

EDIT:
If you have the following, should there be two ViewControllers? or just 1 viewController for both message and accountprofile feature?

```
MESSAGE
ViewMessages
ReadMessage
SendMessage

ACCOUNTPROFILE
ShowAccountProfile
EditAccountProfile
```

Comment: You pretty much only want to use the viewController for messing with the UI and calling other classes that do your math/logic/networking. I've seen people write their entire app in the viewController. It's not even funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Lecture 6](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/147) from CS193P
2. [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) from apple

Answer (score -2):

A view controller should be used to control only 1 single view "main view" which can contain several other views like buttons and so on. I don't know what you are trying to do exactly but my guess is you have 2 views, 1 logged in view and 1 for when the user is not logged in.

You should have 2 view controllers to handle those if thats the case, 1 for the logged in
and 1 for the other.

Try to make sure you are not going to make "god classes" as they're called. Like 1 single class that does everything in your app. Such classes are really hard to maintain and will only lead to weird code architecture

Also give each view controller its own XIB

As Terente lonut Alexandru said, you should read the View Programing Guide on developer.apple.com, it explains about how to do MVC ( Model - View - Controller ) properly

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong.  Typically, one view controller has a view hierarchy with several views in.  The opposite is true though, a view should only usually be controlled by one view controller.